# Copying existing UIImage to new one from property using obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, theos, logos

So I'm trying to access an image but it's not working out, here's what my code looks like. Anyone have any idea what Im doing wrong? error below

```
Tweak.xm:36:36: warning: class method '+_currentNowPlayingArtwork' not found
      (return type defaults to 'id') [-Wobjc-method-access]
  test = [[MPUNowPlayingController currentNowPlayingArtwork] copy];
```

heres my code

```
@interface MPUNowPlayingController : NSObject {
UIImage* _cachedNowPlayingArtwork;
}
@property (nonatomic,readonly) UIImage * currentNowPlayingArtwork;
@property (assign,nonatomic) BOOL shouldUpdateNowPlayingArtwork;
-(BOOL)shouldUpdateNowPlayingArtwork;
-(void)setShouldUpdateNowPlayingArtwork:(BOOL)arg1 ;
-(UIImage *)currentNowPlayingArtwork;
@end

%hook OtherPlaceInSpringboard
//the part where i try to copy the image is below

UIImage *test = [[UIImage alloc] init];
  test = [[MPUNowPlayingController currentNowPlayingArtwork] copy];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:test];
    imageView.alpha = 0.3; //Alpha runs from 0.0 to 1.0
  [self addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: try `  test = [[MPUNowPlayingController currentNowPlayingArtwork] copy];` without the "_"

Comment: @jon-rose i did sorry just been changing everything trying to see if it changes, still same error, will edit to fix this

Comment: you are calling `currentNowPlayingArtwork` as a class method, but it is declared as property of an instance.

Comment: @jon rose sorry i do not have a very strong foundation in coding so im not 100% sure what that means, if you have the time could you show me how I need to change what I have written in the 4th line from bottom? would be appreciated but will try to figure it out so thanks for this help so far

Comment: You have to create a `MPUNowPlayingController` object like `self.myMPUNowPlayingController = [[MPUNowPlayingController alloc] init];` and then use that instance like `[self.myMPUNowPlayingController currentNowPlayingArtwork];`

Comment: @user286152 you got solution?

Comment: @nikdange_me No this didn't end up working for me, though was never sure if its because i wasnt smart enough to figure it out (likely)

Comment: so should i try again?

Comment: @nikdange_me if you think you know a different way to go about it id be interested in trying it out :)